# How to convert CSV string to json (or to c# object's list) without loop? using .NET Framework or .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

Language: C#

.NET Framework 4.7 or .NET Core

I want to know is there any efficient way to convert plain string to JSON (or to C# object list)? Below is my string:

```
"Product","Date","Expiry","Type","Price":"ABC","20-Jul-2019","20-Jul-2022","Supplement","1300":"XYZ","20-Jul-2019","20-Jul-2022","Supplement","100":"AAA","20-Jul-2019","20-Jul-2022","Supplement","200":"XXX","20-Jul-2019","20-Jul-2022","Supplement","500"
```

If you notice, each row is separated by colon (`:`).

I can do it by iterating each line like split(':') then create DataTable then serialize it to JSON but I want to know is there any efficient way to avoid loop and improve performance?

---

**Update**
So far, I have achieved above by using below. It is working fine, but I am looking for someway to avoid the loops.

```
private static DataTable createDataTable(string[] csvArray)
    {
        DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable();
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (var str in csvArray)
        {
            var valueArray = str.Split(',');
            if (idx == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    dtCSV.Columns.Add(valueArray[i].Replace("\"", ""), typeof(String));
                }
                idx++;

            }
            else
            {
                DataRow dr;
                dr = dtCSV.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = valueArray[i].Replace("\"","");
                }
                dtCSV.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
        }
        return dtCSV;

    }
```

Just wondering, we can convert the string to csv using anchor tag's href using below code, is there a way to achieve similar in C# server side. Once it is converted to CSV then also it is easy to save in database table.

```
var csv = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(myString);
```

add above to href of anchor tag using JQuery. It export the data in CSV. But I don't want to export it, I want to save it to database.

Comment: **Typo** alert: **supplement** - not "suppliment" (`e` - not `i` - after the `l`)

Comment: @Cid updated the question. It is working fine but I want to avoid loops as string can be really big.

Comment: You have to parse the string. Parsing is done by examine char for char so you will iterate over every char. Iterating is done by a kind of loop. Avoiding loops is avoiding parse is avoiding getting the job done.

Comment: Are you able to change ':' symbol to a newline in your data? If yes, you can use CsvHelper to map it to objects with a few lines

Comment: @astef I would recommend that too, but OP does not like loops, but I bet CsvHelper is using loops internally.

Comment: *"So far, I have achieved above by using below. It is working fine, but I am looking for someway to avoid the loops"* This question *may* fits [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using LINQ and Json.Net (but will still do loops internally) :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

// -----------

var data = "\"Product\",\"Date\",\"Expiry\",\"Type\",\"Price\":\"ABC\",\"20-Jul-2019\",\"20-Jul-2022\",\"Supplement\",\"1300\":\"XYZ\",\"20-Jul-2019\",\"20-Jul-2022\",\"Supplement\",\"100\":\"AAA\",\"20-Jul-2019\",\"20-Jul-2022\",\"Supplement\",\"200\":\"XXX\",\"20-Jul-2019\",\"20-Jul-2022\",\"Supplement\",\"500\"";
var datas = data.Split(':'); // string[] containing each line of the CSV
var MemberNames = datas[0].Split(','); // the first line, that contains the member names
var MYObj = datas.Skip(1) // don't take the first line (member names)
                 .Select((x) => x.Split(',') // split columns
                                 /*
                                  * create an anonymous collection
                                  * with object having 2 properties Key and Value
                                  * (and removes the unneeded ")
                                  */
                                 .Select((y, i) => new { Key = MemberNames[i].Trim('"'),
                                                         Value = y.Trim('"') })
                                 // convert it to a Dictionary
                                 .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value));

// MYObject is IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>

// serialize (remove indented if needed)
var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MYObj, Formatting.Indented);
Debug.WriteLine(Json);
```

This outputs :

```
[
  {
    "Product": "ABC",
    "Date": "20-Jul-2019",
    "Expiry": "20-Jul-2022",
    "Type": "Supplement",
    "Price": "1300"
  },
  {
    "Product": "XYZ",
    "Date": "20-Jul-2019",
    "Expiry": "20-Jul-2022",
    "Type": "Supplement",
    "Price": "100"
  },
  {
    "Product": "AAA",
    "Date": "20-Jul-2019",
    "Expiry": "20-Jul-2022",
    "Type": "Supplement",
    "Price": "200"
  },
  {
    "Product": "XXX",
    "Date": "20-Jul-2019",
    "Expiry": "20-Jul-2022",
    "Type": "Supplement",
    "Price": "500"
  }
]
```

Comment: yes it will use loops internally but looks clean approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you must correct your string.
Somthing like {"Product":"ABC","Date":"20-Jul-2019",...}

then

```
 return Json(new
            {
                data = "YourStringData",
            });
```

put your string instead of YourStringData

Comment: It is simple but my string is not in above format. It is really plain string. I have updated question with the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple
like this:

string str="{\"name\":\"your name value\",\"age\":26}";

var jv= JsonValue.Parse(str);

Comment: It is simple but my string is not in above format. It is really plain string. I have updated question with the current implementation.